# Discord.js TypeError: connection.play is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, бот, discord-api

Писал дискорд музыкального бота.
Ответов на ошибку нигде не нашёл

Вот и сам код:

```
else if (command === 'music') {
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
      music = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzD0M1MXGqY'
      message.channel.send(`Начинаю воспроизведение: ${music}`);
      const connection = message.member.voice.channel.join();
      const dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(music));
      dispatcher.on("end", end => {
        message.channel.send('Воспроизведение завершено')
        voiceChannel.leave();
      });
    }
```

Вот ошибкаи сама ошибка:

````
const dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(music));
                                    ^

TypeError: connection.play is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (D:\Рабочая папка\zamurbot\main.js:79:37)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (D:\Рабочая папка\zamurbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (D:\Рабочая папка\zamurbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (D:\Рабочая папка\zamurbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (D:\Рабочая папка\zamurbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (D:\Рабочая папка\zamurbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (D:\Рабочая папка\zamurbot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (D:\Рабочая папка\zamurbot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:797:20)```
````

Comment: `channel.join()`, судя по документации, возвращает промис. У промисов нет метода `play()`. Попробуйте `const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();`

Comment: `await is only valid in async function` - теперь вот такая ошибка и ещё бот не запускается

Comment: Значит, объявите функцию, в которой это все происходит, как `async`

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined`

Comment: @Zamur Какую версию discord.js Вы используете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`voiceChannel.join()` - это Promise. Используйте его вместе с `await`

```js
const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
const dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(music));
      dispatcher.on("end", async () => {
        await connection.channel.disconnect();
        return message.channel.send('Воспроизведение завершено');
      });
```